# How to Extract a Value from microservice returned Observable in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, observable, microservices, extract

I am trying to implement NestJS Microservice to Validate my Bearer Token:

Whenever I get TCP response from Microservice which decides whether token is valid or not, it return Observable object, I am unable to extract the response from that Observable, please help me. Not getting proper way to extract the value from Observable in Nestjs, already tried lastValueFrom from RXJS

Here is the Controller to Make a call to Microservice(consumer/caller of microservice):

```
app.controller.ts

    import { Body, Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { PayloadDTO} from './payload.dto';
    
    @Controller()
    export class AppController {
      constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
    
      @Get()
      getHello(): string {
        return this.appService.getHello();
      }
    
      @Post()
      createUserData(@Body() payload: PayloadDTO) {
        const token = header.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
        const isValidToken = this.appService.validateToken(token);
      }
       if(isValidToken) {
         this.appService.CreateRecord(Payload : PayloadDTO)
       } else {
          //Throw New UnathorizedException
       }
       
    }

app.service.ts

import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { PayloadDTO } from './payload.dto';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(
    @Inject('COMMUNICATION') private readonly commClient: ClientProxy
  ) {}

 // service method to call and validate token
  validateToken(token: String) {
    //calling microservice by sending token
    const checkToken: Observable = this.commClient.send({cmd:'validate_token'},token);
   
    //Unable to extract value from Observable here, it is returning observable object
    return extractedResponse; 
  } 

  // service method to create record   
  createRecord(payload: PayloadDTO) {
    //code related to creating new Record
  }
}

app.controller.ts - Microservice Project
    import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    
    @Controller()
    export class AppController {
      constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
    
      @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'validate_token' })
      validateToken() {
        return this.appService.checkToken();
      }
    }
```

Comment: What happened when you used `lastValueFrom`? That method should turn the `Observable` into a `Promise` that you can `await`

Comment: unable to get success, it is printing object

Comment: What object is it printing?

Comment: it is printing observable object

Comment: Can you show the code that's making that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer on my own:

In Microservice Consumer/Caller app.controller.ts I forgot to use await before calling `this.appService.validateToke(token)`

```
      @Post()
      async createUserData(@Body() payload: PayloadDTO) {
        const token = header.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
        const isValidToken = await this.appService.validateToken(token);
      }
```

To convert/extract value from Observable:

In app.service.ts (consumer/caller of microservice) :

1. use async before validateToken
2. use await lastValueFrom(checkToken)
3. return resp

   ```
   // service method to call and validate token
     async validateToken(token: String) {
       //calling microservice by sending token
       const checkToken = this.commClient.send({cmd:'validate_token'},token);
       const resp = await lastValueFrom(checkToken);
       reutn resp;
     }
   ```

Comment: this part   const resp = await lastValueFrom(checkToken);
works for me